# Find sub-pixel maximum on a 2D array

Tags: image, opencv, sum, 2d, convolution

Suppose I have an image and I want to find a subarray with shape 3x3 that contains the maximum sum compared to other subarrays.

How do I do that in python efficiently (run as fast as possible)? If you can provide a sample code that would be great.

My specific problem:
I want to extract the location of the center of the blob in this heatmap

[image]

I don't want to just get the maximum point because that would cause the coordinate to not be very precise. The true center of the blob could actually be between 2 pixels. Thus, it's better to do weighted average between many points to obtain subpixel precision. For example, if there are 2 points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) with values 200 and 100. Then the average coordinate will be `x=(200*x1+100*x2)/300` `y=(200*y1+100*y2)/300`

One of my solution is to do a convolution operation. But I think it's not efficient enough because it requires multiplication to the kernel (which contains only ones). I'm looking for a fast implementation so I cannot do looping myself because I'm not sure if it will be fast.

I want to do this algorithm to 50 images every few milliseconds. (Image come in as a batch). Concretely, think of these images as output of a machine learning model that output heatmaps. In order to obtain the coordinate from these heatmaps, I need to do some kind of weighted average between the coordinates with high intensity. My idea is to do a weighted average around 3x3 area on the image. I am also open to other approaches that can be faster or more elegant.

Comment: You've tagged [tag:convolution], so you've obviously tried convolution/filtering. What were the results? Have you been able to determine the extent (bounding box, maybe?) of the blob? Are the blobs always about the same size? Is there only one blob per image? I would reduce the search area as much as possible (or as much as you can do quickly) and find the weighted centroid of the blob.

Comment: The normal convolution implementation in OpenCV or tensorflow requires that you need to do multiplication to the kernel. It would work but is not the fastest. I want an implementation where you don't need to do any multiplication because only the sum should be enough. Also I think that maybe there are better techniques than convolutions for this problem so I ask it here. If you are able to implement convolution without kernel (and run fast) then I would also want to use that. The blob is always about the same size. Ideally, there should be one blob, but the model could output 2 blobs (wrong).

Comment: Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold, perform morph close, find contours and select largest contour area

Comment: How abou trying `ndimage.center_of_mass`?

Comment: @Alex looks usable around the 3x3 crop of the image, but should not use on the entire image as it will be expensive (at least theoretically, practically never tried)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I ran into this today and I am surprised that I can't find a good answer to this problem.

Comment: You can use the max approach as shown in the accepted answer and then use the center of mass to precisely estimate the true location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking for the "subarray of shape 3x3 with the maximum sum" is the same as looking for the maximum of an image after it has been filtered with an un-normalized 3x3 box filter. So it boils down to finding efficiently the maximum of an image, which you assume is a (perhaps "noisy") discrete sample of an underlying continuous and smooth signal - hence your desire to find a sub-pixel location.

You really need to split the problem in 2 parts:

1. Find the pixel location `m=(xm, ym)` of the maximum value of the image. This requires no more than a visit of every pixel in the image, and one comparison per pixel, so it's O(N) and hence optimal as long as you are operating at the native image resolution. In OpenCv it is done using
   the [minMaxLoc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707) function.
2. Apply whatever model of the image you are using to find its (subpixel-interpolated) maximum in a neighborhood of m.

To clarify point (2): you write

> I don't want to just get the maximum point because that would cause the coordinate to not be very precise. The true center of the blob could actually be between 2 pixels

While intuitively plausible, this assertion needs to be made more precise in order to be computable. That is, you need to express mathematically what assumptions you make about the image, that bring you to search for a "true" maximum between pixel-sampled location.

A simple example for such assumptions is quadratic smoothness. In this scenario you assume that, in a small (say, 3x3, of 5x5) neighborhood of the "true" maximum location, the image signal `z` is well approximated by a quadratic:

```
z = A00 dx^2 + A01 dx dy + A11 dy^2 + A02 dx + A12 dy + A22
where:
dx = x - xm; dy = y - ym
```

This assumption makes sense if the underlying signal is expected to be at least 3rd order continuous and differentiable, because of the Taylor series theorem. Geometrically, it means that you assume (hope?) that the signal looks like a quadric (a paraboloid, or an ellipsoid) near its maximum.

You can then evaluate the above equation for each of the pixels in a neighborhood of `m`, replacing the actual image values for `z`, and thus obtain a linear system in the unknown Aij, with as many equations as there are neighbor pixels (so even a 3x3 neighborhood will yield an over-constrained system). Solving the system in the least-squares sense gives you the "optimal" coefficients Aij. The theoretical maximum as predicted by this model is where the first partial derivatives vanish:

```
del z / del dx = 2 A00 dx + A01 dy = 0
del z / del dy = A01 dx + 2 A11 dy = 0
```

This is a linear system in the two unknown `(dx, dy)`, and solving it yields the estimated location of the maximum and, through the above equation for `z`, the predicted image value at the maximum.

In terms of computational cost, all such model estimations are extremely fast, compared with traversing an image of even moderate size.

Comment: I think your idea of finding the maximum pixel and then average around that pixel is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I did not exactly understand the meaning of your last paragraph so I have just stopped at a point where I got all the coordinates having the maximum value. I have used `cv2.filter2D` for convolution on a thresholded image and then using `np.amax` and `np.where` have found the coordinates having the maximum value.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

img = cv2.imread('blob.png', 0)
start = timer()
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 240, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
res = cv2.filter2D(thresh, -1, mask)
result = np.where(res == np.amax(res))
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

I don't whether it as efficient as you want or not but the output was `0.0013461999999435648 s`

P.S. The image you have provided had a white border which I had to crop out for this method.

Comment: Your idea is similar to what I have in mind where you are trying to convolve the image and then get the maximum result from the new image. Though the time that you used to compute is quite big (1ms). I'm expecting to do this process on 50 images where each image has shape around 100x100 about 50 times a second. Simply put, around 2,500 images will be convolved every second.

Comment: I have added more explanations to clarify what I mean about coordinate weighted average. You can look it in the question again.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to **sub-sampling** the image and find the neighborhood of the desired point. You can make it by doing a loop not on all the pixels but on e.g. every 5 pixels (`row=row+5`and`col=col+5` in the loop). After finding the near location, consider a specific neighborhood around that location and do a loop on whole pixels of that specific crop to find the exact location.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge of image processing, to get a **reliable** result that works for **any** one blob, follow these steps:

1. **Make the image greyscale** if it isn’t already (pixel values 0-255)
2. **Normalise the image** so that pixel intensities cover the full range of 0-255
3. **Convert image to binary** (a pixel is either 0 or 1) - this can be achieved by thresholding, such as applying the rule that any pixel less than or equal to 127 in intensity is given an intensity of 0 and anything else is given an intensity of 1
4. **Find the weighted average** of all the pixels that hold the value of “1”

**or**

4. **Apple an erosion** to the image until you are left with either 2 pixels or 1 pixel.

**Case 1**

If you have two pixels then you need to find the u and v co-ordinates if both pixels. The centre of the blob will be the halfway point between the u and v coordinates of the pixels.

**Case 2**

If you have one pixel left then that pixel’s co-ordinates is the centre point.

—————

You mentioned about achieving this quickly in Python:

Python by design is an interpreted language, so it executed line by line, making it less suitable for highly iterative tasks like image processing. However, you can make use of libraries like OpenCV (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/index.html), which is written in C, to mitigate this apart from making the task at hand a lot easier for you.
**OpenCV also provides solutions for all the steps I listed above in this capacity**, therefore you should be able to achieve a reliable solution fairly quickly, though I can’t say for sure if it will hit your target of 50 images every few milliseconds. Other factors to take into account is the size of the image you are processing. That will increase the processing load exponentially.

**UPDATE**

I just found a good article that practically echoes my step-process:

https://www.learnopencv.com/find-center-of-blob-centroid-using-opencv-cpp-python/

More importantly it also denotes the formula for finding the centroid mathematically as:

c = (1/n)*sigma*(n, i = 1, x_i)

but this is better written in the article than I can do so here.